# This LinearLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting the following warning:

> This LinearLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless;
>   transfer the background attribute to the other view.

Can't figure out what problem is. Read other forums but they didn't help. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:hint="@string/Play_Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:hint="@string/Progress_Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:hint="@string/About_Button" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the outer linear layout, so you could put the UI like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:hint="@string/Play_Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:hint="@string/Progress_Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:hint="@string/About_Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Keepm in mind that you are putting all the components inside the first component you're declaring, that can be a linearLayour, RelativeLayout, Scroolview, ListView, etc.